# could not install extended WPF toolkit(latest version) on visual studio 2013

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, wpftoolkit

I have tried so many times install wpf extended toolkit via Nuget.Here I got an error

```
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5.1', but the package does not contain any assembly 
references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author
```

How to resolve this issue

Comment: Sounds like the WPF toolkit you're trying to install doesn't support .NET 4.5.1.  Maybe you're downloading the wrong version?

Comment: what is the version to fit the framework?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  My comment was just based on the error message.  I'm not familiar with that package.

Answer (score 0):

So I created a blank C# WPF Application solution/project and then went to the project properties setting the framework version to v4.5.1.  Next I went to **Tools** -> **NuGet Package Manager** -> **Manage NuGet Packages for Solution** and in the search filter type **WPF Extended Toolkit**.  This should list v2.5.0 of the Extended.WPF.Toolkit with the Plus version underneath.

By default, any project you have available should be listed on the right hand side as ticked for install if you don't already have the package installed.  Click on **Install** which should give you a preview window saying what it is going to do and confirming will action the change.

In the Output Window, it should be selected to the **Package Manager** in the drop down and there it will list what it has done.  If this fails, can you copy the content of the Package Manager output and paste it in here for us to see.

It should look something like this:

```
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.2.5.0' with respect to project 'WpfApplication1', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.2.5.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.2.5.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.2.5.0'
Adding package 'Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.2.5.0' to folder 'c:\users\netniv\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WpfTestApplication1\packages'
Added package 'Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.2.5.0' to folder 'c:\users\netniv\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WpfTestApplication1\packages'
Added package 'Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.2.5.0' to 'packages.config'
Executing script file 'c:\users\netniv\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WpfTestApplication1\packages\Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.2.5\tools\install.ps1'...


AutoHides             : False
Caption               : Loading...
Collection            : {Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase, 
                        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase, 
                        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase, 
                        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase...}
CommandBars           : {URL Toolbar, F1 Disambiguation Toolbar}
ContextAttributes     : System.__ComObject
DTE                   : System.__ComObject
Document              : 
HWnd                  : 593536
Height                : 856
IsFloating            : False
Kind                  : Tool
Left                  : 31
Linkable              : False
LinkedWindowFrame     : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase
LinkedWindows         : 
Object                : System.__ComObject
ObjectKind            : {E8B06F52-6D01-11D2-AA7D-00C04F990343}
Project               : 
ProjectItem           : 
Selection             : 
Top                   : 106
Type                  : vsWindowTypeToolWindow
Visible               : True
Width                 : 1623
WindowState           : vsWindowStateMaximize
HasBeenDeleted        : False
Events                : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowEvents
VisibilityEvents      : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowVisibilityEvents
Rect                  : 31,106,1623,856
OutstandingEventCount : 0



Successfully installed 'Extended.Wpf.Toolkit 2.5.0' to WpfApplication1
========== Finished ==========
```

Comment: OK, I don't normally create those apps, do you have a sample project or the output of the NuGet as per above?